# Nested array. Third level is disappearing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have that array :

```
$a = array(
    "7" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 6
    ),
    "6" => array(
        "id" => 6,
        "parent" => 5
    ),
    "5" => array(
        "id" => 5,
        "parent" => 4
    ),
    "4" => array(
        "id" => 4,
        "parent" => 0
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 2
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 1
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 0
    )
);
```

the result that I want is that :

```
$a = array(
    "4" => array(
        "id" => 4,
        "parent" => 0,
        array(
            "5" => array(
                "id" => 5,
                "parent" => 4,
                array(
                    "6" => array(
                        "id" => 6,
                        "parent" => 5,
                        array(
                            "7" => array(
                                "id" => 7,
                                "parent" => 6
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 1,
        array(
            "3" => array(
                "id" => 7,
                "parent" => 2
            )
        )
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 0
    )
);
```

the code that I use is this :

```
foreach($a as $v)
{
    if(isset($a[$v['PARENT']]))
    {
        $a[$v['PARENT']][$v['ID']] = $v;
        unset($a[$v['ID']]);
    }
}
```

and the problem that I have is that I get that result :

```
$a = array(
    "4" => array(
        "id" => 4,
        "parent" => 0,
        array(
            "5" => array(
                "id" => 5,
                "parent" => 4
            )
        )
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 1,
        array(
            "3" => array(
                "id" => 7,
                "parent" => 2
            )
        )
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "id" => 7,
        "parent" => 0
    )
);
```

instead of the need it result.

Comment: I already gave you [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671905/nested-array-to-html-list/7672073#7672073) for your problem in your previous question. Didn't it work?

Comment: I have change the form of the data that are comming from my database, and now it is not working. Now the problem is in other position. When I try to pass into the same array, a two dimonsional array into another array element the second dimension is disappearing. What's wrong with that ? :(

Comment: The mistake you make is that you're removing values which you still need. That done, you unset every child of a child, [compare with my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673044/nested-array-third-level-is-disappearing/7673415#7673415), which unsets, too, but references earlier so that the *actual* value does not get removed but preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to properly understand how [variable referencing/aliasing in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) works.

Look at the following example code, which does not look much different to yours but makes use of references in order to access any parent even it has already "moved":

```
# transform $flat into a tree:
foreach($flat as $id => &$value)
{
    # check if there is a parent
    if ($parentId = $value['parent'])
    {
        $flat[$parentId][0][$id] =& $value; # add child to parent
        unset($flat[$id]); # remove reference from topmost level
    }
}
unset($value); # remove iterator reference
print_r($flat); # your tree
```

`$flat` now contains all values from `$flat` - but reordered. [Demo](http://codepad.org/fxCTgsw5).

Comment: Thanks a lot hakre ! Your help was very important to me !

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that output array is correct? Surely the key `2` should be a child of `1` (since `2` has `'parent'=>1`)? If this is not the case, I don't understand what are actually trying to do and how the keys all relate to each other.

If `2` should be a child of `1`, this works:

```
$keep = array();
foreach ($a as $k => &$v) {
  // Loop the array first time and create references to
  // structure the array how you want it
  if ($v['parent']) {
    $a[$v['parent']][0] = array($k => &$v);
  } else $keep[] = $k;
}

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
  // Loop it again to get rid of non-root nodes from the root
  if (!in_array($k,$keep)) {
    unset($a[$k]);
  }
}

print_r($a);
```

Comment: You can put the code from the second foreach into the first one (before you changed the code with `$keep`).

Comment: @Hakre I did think about that, but I don't think you can - if you unset them as you go, and a later element has a parent of the one you have unset, it won't work. I think. I played around with it for a while and couldn't come up with a single loop that actually worked as expected. Would be happy to be proved wrong though...

Comment: Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673044/nested-array-third-level-is-disappearing/7673415#7673415), it has a single loop. And a demo to play with. You can even move the `unset($flat[$id])` *above* the previous line which adds the child to the parent.