# Display tree menu of selected parent

Tags: php, mysql, menu, tree

Here im building a tree menu. A category is accessed by its id and its child displayed.
my function works fine for two level menu but fails to generate level third. Third level menu should be displayed only if id of a second level item clicked. I need this function to track the path to node too. That if a third level id is given than tree should be expanded to third level. i.e. parent of the child and if that parent has a parent too.
mySQL Table

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
|  id   |  title    | parent_id  |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   1   | Computers |    NULL    |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   2   | Dell      |     1      |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   3   | Laptops   |     2      |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   4   | Desktops  |     2      |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   5   | HP        |     1      |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

PHP code

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
 $statement= $db->prepare($sql);
 $statement->execute();
 $categories = array();
 $rootCategories = array();
 while ( $row = $statement->fetchObject() ) {
        $row->childs = array();
        $categories[$row->id] = $row;
        if(empty($row->parent_id)) {
                $rootCategories[$row->id] = $categories[$row->id];
        } else {
                $categories[$row->parent_id]->childs[] = $categories[$row->id];
        }
 }

  function rederTreeById($records, $id=false) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($records as $record) {
                if($id == $record->id) {
                        echo '<li>'.$record->title;
                        if(!empty($record->childs)) {
                                rederTreeById($record->childs);
                        }
                        echo '</li>';
                } else {
                        echo '<li>'.$record->title.'</li>';
                }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
 }


 rederTreeById($rootCategories, 1);
?>
```

For example
if clicked Computers then

- Computer

  - Dell
  - HP

if Dell s clicked then

- Computer

  - Dell

    - Laptops
    - Desktops
  - HP

Comment: I notice you have 2 rows with $row->id = 4.

Comment: Would you please mention where are the two rows on which i mentioned $row->=4?

Comment: Adding two tables also is not the solution of multilevel.

Comment: In this case I don't agree with @joakimdahlstrom, since keeping the entire tree in one table keeps it very flexible when you don't know how deep your structure can bee.

Comment: @Bjørne Malmanger, Absolute right, I didn't read the post well enought. I'll remove my first comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested array. Third level is disappearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673044/nested-array-third-level-is-disappearing)

Comment: In you MySQL table Both Desktops and HP has an ID=4 `+-------+-----------+------------+
|   4   | Desktops  |     2      |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   4   | HP        |     1      |
+-------+-----------+------------+
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem with your solution. When you check for ID `if($id == $record->id)` you will only match the current level in the tree. i.e. selecting Dell with id=2 will not match the first iteration so your function wil not traverse to next level.

You  need to keep track of the path to your selected menu.

In your case. When you select Dell you will only se "Computer", am I right?

How about something like this:

```
...
  function rederTreeById($records, $path) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($records as $record) {
                if(in_array($record->id, $path)) {
                        echo '<li>'.$record->title;
                        if(!empty($record->childs)) {
                                rederTreeById($record->childs, $path);
                        }
                        echo '</li>';
                } else {
                        echo '<li>'.$record->title.'</li>';
                }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
 }

 function getPath($id) {
    $path = array();
    $current=$id;
    $path[] = 1
    while(!is_null($categories[$current]->parent_id)) {
        $current=$categories[$current]->parent_id
        $path[] = $current;
    }
    return $path;
 }


$selectedId = 1;


 rederTreeById($rootCategories, getPath($selectedId));
...
```

Comment: Hi Bjørne, I'm trying to do the same thing but the accepted solution doesn't work for me (the output is not right): please can you help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163449/php-nested-menu-with-a-recursive-function-expand-only-some-nodes-not-all-the